# so_timeout meaning in DBClientReplicaSet signature

Tags: c++, mongodb

Looking to the MongoDB C++ driver documentation (either [the one correspoding to the old driver](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.7.0/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_replica_set.html#a707ed35ffc169054a5a5ef97a2d0ddf7) or the one corresponding to [the new one](http://api.mongodb.org/cxx/legacy-1.0.0/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_replica_set.html#a21993bdf6cb273f0b7911384e1dc34fd)) the signature for the `DBClientReplicaSet` is the following:

```
mongo::DBClientReplicaSet::DBClientReplicaSet(
   const std::string&               name,
   const std::vector<HostAndPort>&  servers,
   double                           so_timeout = 0 
)
```

Althought `name` and `server` are pretty clear, the meaning of the `so_timeout` parameter is not specified.

Not sure if I'm looking to the right documentation pieces, but it would be great if somebody could clarify, please. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's the socket timeout setting. The C++ driver doesn't document what it means, so I'll steal the explanation from the [Python driver docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient):

> socketTimeoutMS: (integer or None) How long (in milliseconds) a send or receive on a socket can take before timing out. Defaults to None (no timeout)

Comment: In the case of C++ driver, the timeout is a double (float) in seconds instead of a long (integer) in miliseconds. Appart from that, I think you are right. Thanks!